# Can I remove additions from a forclosed home?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, foreclosure

I would like to buy a porch off a foreclosed home however removing the porch will leave a huge hole in the side of the home is it legal for this guy to sell me the addition he added on? to add the porch he changed the structure of the main roof to support his addition.

**EDIT**

More info was added in this related question:
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46976/selling-additions-off-forclosed-home

> The house is in Kentucky. This man is the previous buyer he let the loan go
>   after he divorced.  Now the lenders are taking the house and in fact some
>   preparations have been made to move the structure. I was trying to
>   save a buck. You guys are really helpful, thank you all.

Comment: Is this "guy" the previous owner? House has already been foreclosed on and is in the bank's hands or sold by the sheriff?

Comment: This is a question more of law than of personal finance, but, as mikkel suggested, if the house _has_ already been foreclosed on, then the house _and all its fixtures and additions_ are owned by the bank. The "guy" cannot sell off the porch any more than he can sell off the (installed) dishwasher or kitchen cabinets; they are part and parcel of the house that the "guy" no longer owns. I do wonder why **you** want to pay to have a porch removed from a house and installed on your own house, instead of just having your own house remodeled to add on a brand-new porch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about law than personal finance.

Answer (score 5):

First, everywhere in the US that I know of the porch is part of the house.   It would fall under most code ordinances as a permanent fixture.  There is actually a lot of code around porches/decks.  To be considered permanent it has to be attached in the ground or to the house (yours sounds like both).

Secondly, any change like this to the house would have to be approved by the local town and the inspector.

Third, you are just stealing this from the bank and aiding a thief.  It is possible that the bank (not likely but possible) could come after you with both civil and criminal charges.  The bank would definitely be going after the previous owner.  Don't get wrapped up into this (and relocating a porch is usually not worth the time/effort).